# Флаги, или аналог множества в C#, как лучше реализовать?

Tags: c#, множества

Есть некий метод, пусть `public static bool IsNewFileActual(sting oldFile, string newFile, ComparsionFlags flags)` сравнивающий 2 файла по набору критериев. Сами критерии, для наглядности, например, такие: сравнение по дате последней записи в файл, версия файла, MD5-хэш, размер файла.

В зависимости от некоторых условий, должна формироваться переменная flags, которая будет задавать флаги для критериев проверки (например, флаг проверки по номеру версии будет справедлив для *.EXE и *.DLL, а вот для *.PNG или *.HTML он не нужен).

В паскале (Delphi), я бы работал примерно так:

```
type 
   TComparsionFlags = set of (cfDate, cfVersion, cfHash, cfSize);
var
  CF : TComparsionFlags;
...
CF := [];
CF := CF + [cfVersion]; 
...
СF := CF + [cfHash, cfSize];
...
CF := CF - [cfDate];
...
if (cfDate in CF) then 
  begin
  ...
  end;
```

Иными словами, описал бы множество с возможными флагами, и использовал бы средства языка для достижения своих целей.

Насколько я знаю, аналога паскалевских множеств в C# в чистом виде нет, и в качестве замены можно использовать `enum`, что я и делаю:

```
[Flags]
public enum ComparsionFlags : byte
{
    cfVersion = 1,
    cfSize = 2,
    cfDate = 4,
    cfHash = 8,
}
```

После чего перед вызовом метода `IsNewFileActual` объявляю переменную `ComparsionFlags flags` и далее задаю флаги так:

```
flags = ComparsionFlags.cfSize | ComparsionFlags.cfDate | ComparsionFlags.cfHash;
```

Как по мне, так это не очень удобно (по меньшей мере, как минимум, не лаконично), как для задания самой переменной `flags`, так и для проверок значений, которые переданы в этой переменной внутрь метода.

Собственно, вопрос и в заголовке, и вот, более детально:

**Как наилучшим образом реализовать тип `ComparsionFlags` для использования переменных данного типа в качестве набора флагов?**

Может быть есть альтернативные, более удобные способы выполнить описанную задачу?

Буду признателен за внимание и дельные советы/ответы. Спасибо.

P.S. Думал про `List<T>` и `HashTable`, но есть ощущение, что это несколько не то... Например, ничто не мешает добавить в `List` какой-то флаг n раз, и при удалении этого флага из списка придется просматривать его весь, и удалять все вхождения этого флага (или флагов), т.е. получаем, что нужно довольно много обвязки вокруг списка делать.

Comment: Думал про использование List<T>, но, почему-то кажется, что это как из пушки по воробьям...

Comment: *ничто не мешает добавить в List какой-то флаг n раз* - есть коллекции в которые два раза не добавить, например Dictionary

Comment: Способ которым вы выполняете описаную задачу оптимален. По поводу лаконичности: Приведённый код объявления и использования битовых флагов на Делфи не особо компактнее. Если сократить имя вашего перечисления до CompFl убрать явное указание значений перечисления (насколько я помню компилятор может это сделать за вас) и выписать всё в строку-выйдет компактнее чем на делфях

Comment: @4per, я понимаю, вот и хотелось бы получить ответы и мнения, кто как решал (или решал бы) аналогичную задачу.

Comment: Таки этот красивый или некрасивый способ - самый лучший. Лаконичнее - развечто пользоваться константами 1 2 4 8 напрямую, возможно даже так `1/*version*/ | 2/*size*/`

Comment: Есть такая штука как `HashSet`, посмотрите еще и в ее сторону.

Comment: _Думал про List<T> и HashTable_ - [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) хранит только уникальные значения

Comment: Что же, ответы и комментарии вполне исчерпывающие, огромное спасибо! Для себя, помимо прочего, открыл еще [вот такую статью](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23391/Set-Collections-for-C), в которой проведен обзор и даны ссылки на некоторые существующие в C# реализации множеств (set of...) и операций с ними. Надеюсь, эта информация окажется полезной, если вдруг возникнет аналогичный вопрос у кого-либо еще. Для своей же задачи я не стал изобретать велосипед с треугольными колесами и множить сущности, оставив её реализацию через `enum` и учитывая некоторые полезности, данные в [этом ответе](ht

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использование флагов выглядит достаточно лаконично. Если переписать код с Delphi, получится примерно так:

```
ComparsionFlags CF = default(ComparsionFlags);

CF = CF | ComparsionFlags.cfVersion; 
...
СF = CF | ComparsionFlags.cfHash | ComparsionFlags.cfSize;
...
CF = CF & ~ComparsionFlags.cfDate;
...
if (CF.HasFlag(ComparsionFlags.cfDate)) { 
  ...
}
```

Если использовать [using static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sf0df423.aspx#mt3), то имя enum можно опускать:

```
using static ComparsionFlags;
...

ComparsionFlags CF = default(ComparsionFlags);

CF |= cfVersion; 
...
СF |= cfHash | cfSize;
...
CF &= ~cfDate;
...
if (CF.HasFlag(cfDate)) { 
  ...
}
```

В противовес, можно использовать класс [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx), как указано в соседнем ответе:

```
HashSet<ComparsionFlags> flags = new HashSet<ComparsionFlags>();

CF.Add(ComparsionFlags.cfVersion); 
...
СF.UnionWith(new[]{ComparsionFlags.cfHash,ComparsionFlags.cfSize});
...
CF.Remove(ComparsionFlags.cfDate);
...
if (CF.Contains(ComparsionFlags.cfDate)) { 
  ...
}
```

Как можно заметить, в этом случае не обязательно делать значения enum флагами, то есть значения могут идти и подряд: *1,2,3...*, а не *1,2,4...*

Answer (score 4):

Я бы написал `HashSet<ComparsionFlags>`

Comment: @Ksenia, ну почему? вполне себе решение: использовать конкретный класс